# use-package and dependencies

Tags: init-file, use-package, dependency

Given a major mode package `foo` and `foo-x` that extends `foo`, with feature `x` is there a recommended way to configure them with `use-package` (assuming `:defer t` and `:ensure t` for all?

- nested use-package

  ```
  (use-package foo
      :config
      (use-package foo-x
          :ensure t))
  ```
- requite

  ```
  (use-package foo
     :config
     (require 'foo-x))

  (use-package foo-x)
  ```
- after:

  ```
  (use-package foo)

  (use-package foo-x
      :after foo)
  ```
- hook

  ```
  (use-package foo)

  (use-package foo-x
      :hook foo)
  ```

Or some other different way. What are the pros an cons of each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use-package` is a macro around `require`. Macros are expanded before code execution. The purpose of a macro is to create syntactic sugar to make code easier to read, understand, and maintain. Your different alternatives have minimal effect to the execution time. In the end, it is a personal choice which one you prefer.

I use mostly the `:after` key for terseness, but sometimes nest short `use-package` calls within larger ones to make sure all relevant code stays in one place.

You should check yourself what the use-package macro does. Install `macro-expand`, place cursor before the macro and call `macro-expand` to see how the expanded code looks like.